# jQuery - removing an element does not remove the associated rules and error messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my page, I've a set of basic input elements. In addition to these, I've another bunch of input elements that I add and remove dynamically based on some conditions. While adding, I attach jQuery events, rules and messages to them. Everything is working fine to this point.

1. Removing these elements (using 'remove' or 'empty' method), does not remove the associated rules and messages. The jQuery documentation is specific that removing an element removes the associated events but it is not clear about rules. At present, I'm removing these rules by iterating through these elements. Is there a better way?
2. Same is the case with label.error. Removing the input elements does not automatically remove the error messages, neither the hidden ones nor the displayed ones. At present, I'm iterating through the input elements, querying for the error message labels (using 'for=elementid') and removing them. Is there a better way?

I'm using the validation plug-in and the rules and messages are associated with it. Here is a code-snippet:

```
//remove the rules
$('.typeProperty').each(function(){ $(this).rules('remove'); });
//remove the input elements
$('#typeDiv').empty();
```

where 'typeProperty' is the class I've associated with the dynamically inserted elements.

Following is the code snippet for removing the error messages:

```
for (var i in inputElements) {
   //jQuery messages
   $("label.error[for={0}]".format(inputElements[i].attr('id'))).remove();
   //custom messages
   $("label.cerror[for={0}]".format(inputElements[i].attr('id'))).remove();
}
```

Where 'inputElements' is an array of dynamically added input elements

Comment: are you using validation plugin? Is that the `rules` you mention?

Comment: Sharing your code or a working example will help get a good answer.

Comment: I've edited my question and added the some more details.